# Legend texts for bar chart cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css, legend

I got a legend for stacked bar chart. However, the texts for the legend are getting cut off:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
var options ={
    title: 'No. of cases by Planning Area(Islandwide)',
    vAxis: { title: '', titleTextStyle: { color: 'black'} },
    chartArea : {top :20,right : 45},
    isStacked: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 1600,
    colors: ['#cab2d6', '#b2df8a','#1f78b4','#33a02c','#a6cee3','#ffff99','#ff7f00','#e31a1c','#6a3d9a','#fb9a99','#cccccc'],
    fontSize: getFontSize(),
    legend:{ alignment: 'center', textStyle: { fontSize: getFontSize(), overflow: 'auto'} }
};


var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('pieOne'));
chart.draw(data,options);
$(".chart").colorbox({ inline: true, open: true, width: 800, height: 800});
```

Although I set the autoflow property for legend already but it still getting cut off. I wonder why is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try increasing `width:` in `options`?

Comment: Can you show us your html code or a working example?

Comment: increasing width works but there is no scrollbar for ipad version. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: I do not have html code for this because it is all done in .js file